# Extract bucket size from binned column using Pandas' cut function

Tags: python, pandas, extract, cut, binning

I would like to be able to read from a column which is transformed from a continuous/integer to a categorical column using Pandas' cut what the bin size is. Why? Because I have a case where I can't access the code which cuts the column but I can access the resulting column itself and I want to log the binsize that is used.

For example:

```
pd.cut(np.array([1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3]), bins=np.arange(0, 10, 2))
Out[11]: 
[(0, 2], (6, 8], (4, 6], (2, 4], (4, 6], (2, 4]]
Categories (4, interval[int64]): [(0, 2] < (2, 4] < (4, 6] < (6, 8]]
```

I would like to be able to retrieve that in this case the bin size is 2. I could create some code that reads the intervals from the string that defines the bins but that is not really a stable solution I would say. I also tried to inspect the attributes of the resulting object e.g.

```
pd.cut(np.array([1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3]), bins=np.arange(0, 10, 2))._dtype._categories._left.__dict__
```

But that also didn't give me any results.

Answer (score 0):

One way can be using [np.ediff1d()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html) -

```
out, bins = pd.cut(np.array([1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3]), bins=np.arange(0, 10, 2), retbins=True)
bins[1] - bins[0] # np.ediff1d(bins)[0] OR np.diff(bins)[0]
```

You can also use [`np.diff()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

OR, the plain old simple `bins[1] - bins[0]` way!

**Output**

```
2
```

Comment: In this case the code does not return a bins object, it only creates a new column in a dataframe using the cut() function.